# How to do this redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to 301 redirect all the link from

```
http://www.mysite.com/my-color/whatever/
```

to

```
http://www.mysite.com/my-color/
```

htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^my\-color\/\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.mysite\.com\/my\-color\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

This throws me in a loop ad can't seem to figure it out... Do you have any pointers ? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `(.*)` to `(.+)`. That way it won't match the empty string.